# Summing text inputs in which the number of inputs changes based on a for loop

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, loops, onchange

Okay so here's the problem. I currently have a javascript that successfully sums all of the input boxes.

```
    <script>
    function myFunction(tBox)
    {
    var a=document.getElementById("hous1");
    var b=document.getElementById("hous2");
    var c=document.getElementById("hous3");
    w=Number(a.value);
    x=Number(b.value);
    y=Number(c.value);
    t=w+x+y;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=t;
    }
    </script>
```

Where the number of text input boxes are dynamically created and given unique names based on:

```
   <?php
   for ($i=1; $1<=$housingcount; $i++){
   echo '<input size="',11,'" type="text" name="cavqty',$i,'" id="hous',$i,'" onchange="myFunction(value)"/>
   ?>
```

Where $housingcount simply count the number of rows that match the mysql query.
Also, the function is simply outputted using:

```
    <p id="test"></p>
```

This code works fine as long as the number of text input boxes equals three. My question is how do I write my javascript to be able to take any number of text inputs, instead of being limited to a predefined number, such as three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to examine all input elements and examine their name, checking for the prefix "hous".  For example:

```
var sum = 0;

var elts = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for( var i=0; i<elts.length; i++ ) {
    var elt = elts[i];
    if( elt.id && elt.id.indexOf( 'hous' ) === 0 ) sum += Number( elt.value );
}

console.log( sum );
```

This solution doesn't need jQuery.  See it in action here:

http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/xmrGu

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but this can sum all your inputs, considering that only integers, if you wanna float, just tell me that I'll find out.

HTML

```
<input size="11" type="text" name="cavqty" id="hous" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)"/>
<input size="11" type="text" name="cavqty" id="hous" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)"/>
<input size="11" type="text" name="cavqty" id="hous" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)"/>
```

Javascript

```
totalSum = 0;
myFunction = function (value) {
    totalSum += parseInt(value, 10);
    console.log(totalSum);
}
```

You can see working at [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcLVE/)